# Date is displaying as one day before to the front end from the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, date, mysql-workbench

I'm using mysql database, If I give any input to the date today it is taking as the current date(10-01-2019). But the problem is that it is showing as one day before(09-01-2019) to the front end. I've not used any streams in this. Date datatype has been tried as Instant, LocalDate.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Is this for all dates?  Have you ruled out a timezone mismatch between the client, the server and the recorded date?

Comment: the datatype is set as date in the database

Comment: According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html), `DATE` data-type maps to java class `java.sql.Date`. The string representation of a `java.sql.Date` instance does not always truly reflect the actual value. Perhaps my [now ancient] article will be of help: [What's your time zone?](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073786/what-s-your-time-zone-.html)

Comment: Perhaps a [mcve] is appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

- Check db timezone:

  `SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;`

  or

  `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`
- Check your local pc timezone.

If they differ:

```
SET time_zone='00:00';
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to store the date in this format YYYY-MM-DD.
This is why you see a different date